# How to remove repeated sentences from a string

Tags: python

I have an issue that I do not know how to tackle.

For example: I have a string returning in a function that has multiple sentences separatade by a comma. And some of them are comming repeated:

Like:

`"lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor"`

I need to remove these sentences that are comming repeated but without checking word-by-word, rather sentence by sentence striped by ",". Since there may have other sentences with repeated words that should not be removed.

**Input example:**

`"lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol"`

**Output desired:**

`"lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol"`

Comment: You can split by commas, strip the whitespace, and put the result in a set.  That eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @elias do you mean even if this occurs later in the sentence? or just if they are outputted sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on the [Tim Roberts comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75074306/how-to-remove-repeated-sentences-from-a-string#comment132483154_75074306). The only difference is `OrderedDict` usage in order to preserve sentences order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

string = 'lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol'
string = ', '.join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(string.split(', ')))
print(string)
```

Output:

```
lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol
```

Answer (score 1):

since python 3.6 the dict class keeps the items ordered. so we can also use regular dict, no additional modul is required.
the code splits by ', ' and also strips off all leading or trailing whitespaces.

```
txt = "lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor , lorem mark dol"
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(map(str.strip, txt.split(',')))
print(*my_dict, sep=', ')
```

result is:
`lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not based on [Tim Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1883316/tim-roberts) comment but utilizes the same tools:

```
text = "lorem ipsum dolor, lorem ipsum dolor, lorem mark dol"
text = ', '.join(set(list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), text.split(",")))))
```

The difference with [Alderven's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255764/alderven) answer is no imports.